# How enable pdo_mysql

Tags: mysql, php, centos5, pdo

I am trying to install [SpaceBukkit](http://spacebukkit.xereo.net). I was wondering how I enable `pdo_mysql`. When trying to setup the MySQL part I get this error:

```
The "pdo_mysql" extension is NOT loaded in your `php.ini`! 
Make sure to load it before continuing!
```

This is not a cPanel server, so I can only rely off of ssh and ftp (sftp). If you guys could please let me know it would be greatly appreciated!

As a side note, I am on Centos 5.

Answer (score 9):

Install pdo:

```
yum install php-devel php-pear mysql-devel httpd-devel
pecl install pdo
PHP_PDO_SHARED=1 pecl install pdo_mysql
```

Then edit the `/etc/php.ini` file with your favorite commandline texteditor (vi, vim, nano,...) (access the machine through ssh) and add these lines:

```
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

Restart the webserver and you should be all set. Cudos to http://karoshiethos.com/2008/07/24/installing-pdo_mysql-on-centos/

Comment: Where do I add the:
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
Where in the file?

Comment: at the end or wherever extension is defined.

Comment: What do you mean wherever the extension is defined?

Comment: Have you even tried opening the php.ini file?

Comment: Yea I have. Just I don't know where to add it. Sorry bout that.

Comment: What about 'WARNING: "pecl/PDO" is deprecated in favor of "channel://http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/pdo//ext/PDO"' ? The link you provide is very old...

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue, the problem for me was a missing php to mysql library. In CentOs I fixed it by running `# yum install php-mysql` and then restarting apache with `# /bin/systemctl restart  httpd.service` Note that the naming is slightly different from debian/ubuntu based distros, php->php5 and httpd->apache2.